# How to keep the text colors in vim cursorline?

Tags: vim

How only change the background of the cursorline of vim but keep the original text colors?
As shown in the picture, the cursorline is darker than the regular lines.
How do we make the cursor line brighter or just keep the text colors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `ctermbg` to any colour you want [from this chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg). The value must be a number from 0 through 255.